# Start sequence on a variable column without "array not expanded" error?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In one sheet, I have columns for each month. In another sheet, I define `start countdown in:` with a cell `04/2023` and `# of months` as `4`.

The desired result is starting under April 2023, I want to see a countdown of 4, 3, 2, 1 for four months.

I can use the formula `=sequence(1, Rules!$B$26 + 1, Rules!$B$26, -1)` but only if I manually add it under April 2023.

I tried doing `=if(text(B1,"MMyyyy")=text(Rules!$B$25,"MMyyyy"),sequence(1, Rules!$B$26 + 1, Factors!$B$26, -1),)` for all the cells in the row, but it gives the error "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a generalized scenario of how it can be done:

```
=index(xlookup(A$1:L$1,edate(N2,sequence(O2,1,0,1)),sequence(O2,1,O2,-1),))
```

- the ***rules*** are in `Columns N,O` of this sample dataset

[image]